# Validation in Model in MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

What is the possible reason and solution to this problem? why is it not working i'm stock here for almost an hour don't know what is the problem.

**VIEW**

```
@model Sanipex.Models.WarehouseGoodsIN
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div align="center">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.missinglabel)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.missinglabel)
</div>
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Confirm"/>
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class WarehouseGoodsIN
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int missinglabel { get; set; }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult ScanLabel(WarehouseGoodsIN goodsin, string btnsubmit)
{
      if (btnsubmit == "Confirm") 
      {
          if (ModelState.IsValid) //modelstate value is false 
          {
             db.WarehouseGoodsINs.Add(goodsin);
             db.SaveChanges();
          }
          return RedirectToAction("ScanLabelMenu");
      }
}
```

Comment: could you add your controller codes?

Comment: ensure that u r taking input type submit button to post form data...

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi i include the controller codes

Comment: A question for you, when you put a break point in the Action is there even an ID being passed? You have stated ID is a KEY, ensure this is passed in as if it cannot find it then its going to find an error (not 100% certain though as never needed KEY data annotation). Just add it as a hidden textbox as the view is rendered, alternatively get rid of the KEY attribute on ID and see what happens. If it works without the key then there is your problem.

Comment: @Damian if i remove the "if(ModelState.IsValid)" the value in the textbox will save to the database. that means it has a value right? the value i inputed in the textbox is being pass to the model.

Comment: MissingLabel may be passed to the model, however you aren't passing an ID so with the KEY DataAnnotation in the View Model it might be stating the ModelState is invalid. Remove the KEY DataAnnotation and  see what happens, if the modelstate comes back as TRUE then you don't need the KEY attribute. If the database is AutoGenerating a number for that field then you do not need the KEY attribute anyway. I'll post an example of what you should do.

Comment: Reynan where exactly you want the validation?

Comment: zzzz i think i know the answer the textbox is in a modal. when it refresh to the same page it is close. there is actually a button to open the modal to input the missing label. now i know. thanks everyone i'm stupid haha i thought it will validate first before going to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it could be a problem with lack of of `submit` button in your view. So, your code should looks like:

```
@model Sanipex.Models.WarehouseGoodsIN
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div align="center">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.missinglabel)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.missinglabel)
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>

</div>
}
```

What is more, you should consider to use server-side validation. Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(WarehouseGoodsIN model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //some logic here
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if modelState is not valid you should pass model to view again, because validation metadatas are storing in model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ScanLabel(WarehouseGoodsIN goodsin, string btnsubmit)
{
    if (btnsubmit == "Confirm") 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) //modelstate value is false 
        {
             db.WarehouseGoodsINs.Add(goodsin);
             db.SaveChanges();

             return RedirectToAction("ScanLabelMenu");
        }
        else
        {
            // this line is necessary for model validation
            return View(goodsin);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you dont need to check if submit button is clicked.

---

**UPDATE**

Just before `if (ModelState.IsValid)` remove Id index using this line `ModelState.Remove("Id")` this way when MVC team remove this bug, you just need to remove this line code of your projects.

Still having this issue when using MVC 5, Database First and Entity Framework 6. Having only when using ViewModels though.

**View**

```
@model Sanipex.Models.WarehouseGoodsIN
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div align="center">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.missinglabel)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.missinglabel)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Confirm"/>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ScanLabel(WarehouseGoodsIN goodsin, string btnsubmit)
{
    if (btnsubmit == "Confirm") 
    {
        ModelState.Remove("Id")
        if (ModelState.IsValid) //modelstate value is false 
        {
             db.WarehouseGoodsINs.Add(goodsin);
             db.SaveChanges();

             return RedirectToAction("ScanLabelMenu");
        }
        else
        {
            // this line is necessary for model validation
            return View(goodsin);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean if i remove the if (ModelState.IsValid) the value in the textbox will save to the database

Comment: i know my mistake already i'm stupid haha. just another question how can i put validate into @Html.TextBox("txtfirstname")

Comment: add `txtfirstname` to your model, or create a viewmodel. For model edit operations, always use viewmodels, so you can add new object if you want...

Comment: how do i explain this i can't use model every time. my project is like an mobile app. step by step example. i have model Id,name,address. my page is one at a time. input name then go to another page and input address after all is done. i will save it to the database. i use session to store the values :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you should structure your ViewModel, I have found no use for the KEY data annotation as it stands.

```
Public int ID { get; set; }
[Required]
Public string MissingLabel { get; set; }
```

From here structure the action similar to you have done (example below).

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult ActionName(WarehouseGoodsIN model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //Do Something
    }

    Return View(mode)
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on 'ModelState.IsValid' expand the 'Values' part when you scroll over the ModelState. Then check each result and see what errors are being thrown.

Comment: @Damian check the comment in this answer by user
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568463/validation-in-model-in-mvc-not-working/24568992#24568992

Answer (score 0):

try adding these in the sequence :

First

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Then

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```